# Populate MUI Select menu items from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I am trying to populate an MUI select with choices from an API's JSON response.  Currently, all `Choices` are being pushed into one `MenuItem` within the Select.  [image: Menu Item Visual]

The Choices are likely to change in the future so I would like to avoid hard coding them.

How can I apply a `.map` to get the `MenuItems`to display the JSON `Choices` separately rather than having them display on the same line.

Here is my JSON, and below is how I am displaying all other data.

```
{
  "question_groups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "DDD",
      "questions": [
        {
          "Question": "1. Do you want a Drink?",
          "QuestionType": "Single Choice",
          "Response": null,
          "Choices": [
            "Yes",
            "No"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "SizingId": null
    },
}
```

```
const SelectQuestion = ({ question }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField value={question?.Question || ""} />
      <Select label="Question" >
        <MenuItem value={question?.Choices || ""}>{question?.Choices || ""}</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      <Divider />
    </Box>
  );
};

const TextQuestion = ({ question }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField />
      <TextField />
      <Divider />
    </Box>
  );
};

const questionComps = questions["question_groups"]?.map((group, i) => {
  return group["questions"]?.map((question, i) => {
    return question["QuestionType"] === "Text" ? (
      <TextQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question} />
    ) : (
      <SelectQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question} />
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `SelectQuestion`  component by mapping through your `"Choices"` options and render `MenuItem`-s accordingly.

```
const SelectQuestion = ({ question }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <TextField value={question?.Question || ""} />
      <Select label="Question">
        {question.Choices.map((choice) => (
          <MenuItem key={choice} value={choice}>
            {choice}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <Divider />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-x15ter)

Comment: This solution works, but in an unexpected way.  ``Choices`` are now available as individual options within the Select, but they are rendering on the same line/Menu Item.

Comment: Make sure you didn't make a typo or overwrite any styles. I attached the demo where each option takes its own row.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the solution straight from your answer.  I took a look at your Demo, and it is structured the same.  I have removed any styling but that made no difference.